# Combine two columns of a table in third column

Tags: sql-server

I want to create a table wherein the 'Id' column is combined with 'Category' column and gets stored in 'UserId' column. Here is an example.

```
Id    Category    UserId
1     STD         STD1
2     NMM         NMM2
3     COV         COV3
```

I have tried something like this :

```
 Create table tblUsers
 (
   Id int identity primary key,
   RegId as RIGHT('0000'+CAST([Id] as varchar(5)),5),
   Category nvarchar(3),
   UserId CONCAT(CategoryInitials,Id)
 )
```

but this doesnt work. So, how does that work WHILE CREATING THIS TABLE?

Comment: Consider Using a [computed column](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188300.aspx) instead.  Unless you don't want it to get updated when the id and category change...

Comment: id,category don't change

Answer (score 3, accepted):

May be like this:

```
Create table tblUsers
 (
 Id int identity primary key,
 Category nvarchar(3),
 UserId as (Category + cast(Id as varchar(10)))
 )
```

Comment: UserId as (Category + RIGHT('0000'+CAST([Id] as varchar(5)),5))..worked for me.